# Como inserir em 3 tabelas ao mesmo tempo? (PHP +Mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Sempre venho aqui para pesquisa mas nunca precisei perguntar. Agora me encontro em uma encruzilhada.

Preciso adicionar dados em 3 tabelas ao mesmo tempo( livros, autor e editor), sendo que em livro, eu tenho chave estrangeira de editor e autor.

No sql consegui algo desse tipo:

```
INSERT INTO autor(nome) VALUES ('testeAutor');
INSERT INTO livros(titulo, edicao, id_autor) values ('nomedolivro','segunda edicao',LAST_INSERT_ID());
INSERT INTO editora(nome) VALUES('testeEditora');
UPDATE livros set id_editora=LAST_INSERT_ID() where titulo='nomedolivro';
```

Em php, até consegui algo desse tipo e funcionou:

```
$query_autor = "insert into autor (nome) values ('$autor')";
            $sql_autor = mysqli_query($con, $query_autor) or die("Não foi possível cadastrar o autor.");
            $id_autor = mysqli_insert_id($con);
            $query_editora = "insert into editora (nome) values ('$editora')";
            $sql_editora = mysqli_query($con, $query_editora) or die("Não foi possível cadastrar a editora.");
            $id_editora = mysqli_insert_id($con);
            $sql = "insert into livros (titulo, edicao, id_autor, id_editora) values ('$titulo', '$edicao', '$id_autor', '$id_editora')";
            echo $sql;
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("Não foi possível inserir o novo livro no sistema.");
            if(!$result) {
                echo "Não foi possivel cadastrar o novo livro";
            } else {
            echo "Livro cadastrado com sucesso";
            echo "<br />";
            echo "<a href='cadastro.php'>Voltar para cadastro</a>";
            echo "<br />";
            echo "<a href='index.php'>Listar todos</a>";
```

Tem algum jeito menos "Gambiarra" e/ou mais seguro de se fazer isso?
Até porque, pode acontecer de inserir o autor, editor e falhar o livro...
Tentei begin tran, start transaction... Nada funciona no xampp. Se eu boto qualquer um deses (pesquisei no google, olhei na doc do mysql), ele da que o codigo está incorreto na proxima linha após o BEGIN ou START.

Desde já agradeço a atenção galera!

---

Update: Consegui botar pra funcionar com START TRANSACTION; + COMMIT; via SQL porém queria saber se tem algum jeito mais correto ou usual de colocar isso em php. Está uma zona desse jeito que postei em cima. Teria que criar mais uma variavel só pro START TRANSACTION ou tem algum comando no php para fazer isso? 
Não sei nem exatamente como pesquisar no google sobre isso.

Comment: exemplos de transacção [aqui](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php).

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu saiba o MySQL não suporta alguma maneira de inserir em varias tabelas ao mesmo tempo.

O que pode fazer é abrir uma transação, rodar os inserts e depois fazer o commit. Sendo assim, se ocorrer um erro em um dos inserts os demais não serão efetivamente gravados no banco.

Comment: Então Fábio. Tentei de todos os modos que conheço mas o mysql do xampp não está aceitando os comandos de iniciar e fechar transação.
Tentei BEGIN TRAN, BEGIN TRANSACTION, START TRAN, START TRANSACION... enfim, eu boto o comando sozinho e ele funciona, se eu tentar usar o begin ou start, ele diz que o insert que estava certo, ficou errado...

Answer (score -1):

Tenho uma resposta muito extensa. Mas talvez sirva para dar um norte.
Minha ideia é que você separe as camadas do programa.

Tentei expressar de forma bastante genérica abaixo:

```
<?php
// Contexto do modelo da livraria.
class Editora {

    public function __constructor($nome) {
        $this->nome = $nome;
    }

    /**
     * @var int numero Identificador.
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @var string Texto com nome.
     */
    public $nome;

}

class EditoraCRUD {

    public function cadastrar(Editora $Editora, PDOStatement $Connect) {
        // Contexto do crud do editora sempre utilizando a mesta conexão.
        $Param = [$Editora->id, $Editora->nome];
        $statement = $Connect->prepare("INSERT INTO Editora VALUES (:ID, :Nome)");
        $statement->bindParam(":ID", $Param[0]);
        $statement->bindParam(":Nome", $Param[1]);
        $statement->execute();
        $Editora->id = $Connect->lastInsertId();
    }

}

class Autor {

    public function __constructor($nome) {
        $this->nome = $nome;
    }

    /**
     * @var int numero Identificador.
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @var string Texto com nome.
     */
    public $nome;

}

class AutorCRUD {

    public function cadastrar(Autor $Autor, PDOStatement $Connect) {
        // Contexto do crud do Autor sempre utilizando a mesta conexão.
        $Param = [$Autor->id, $Autor->nome];
        $statement = $Connect->prepare("INSERT INTO Autor VALUES (:ID, :Nome)");
        $statement->bindParam(":ID", $Param[0]);
        $statement->bindParam(":Nome", $Param[1]);
        $statement->execute();
        $Autor->id = $Connect->lastInsertId();
    }

}

class Livro {

    public function __constructor($nome) {
        $this->nome = $nome;
    }

    /**
     * @var int numero Identificador.
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @var string Texto com nome.
     */
    public $nome;

    /**
     * @var Autor Instancia de Autor.
     */
    public $Autor;

    /**
     * @var Editora Instancia de Editora.
     */
    public $Editora;

}

class LivroCRUD {

    public function cadastrar(Livro $Livro, PDOStatement $Connect) {
        // Contexto do crud do Livro sempre utilizando a mesta conexão.
        $Param = [$Livro->id, $Livro->nome, $Livro->Autor->id, $Livro->Editora->id];
        $statement = $Connect->prepare("INSERT INTO Livros VALUES (:ID, :Nome, :Autor, :Editora)");
        $statement->bindParam(":ID", $Param[0]);
        $statement->bindParam(":Nome", $Param[1]);
        $statement->bindParam(":Autor", $Param[2]);
        $statement->bindParam(":Editora)", $Param[3]);
        $statement->execute();
        $Livro->id = $Connect->lastInsertId();
    }

}

// Contexto do controller da livraria.
$Connect = new PDO("mysql:127.0.0.1@livraria", "root", "");

$Editora = new Editora("StackOverflow em Português");
EditoraCRUD::cadastrar($Editora, $Connect);

$Autor = new Autor("Luis");
LivroCRUD::cadastrar($Autor, $Connect);

if (isset($Editora->id) && isset($Autor->id)) {
    $Livro = new Livro("Suas Respostas");
    $Livro->Autor = $Autor;
    $Livro->Editora = $Editora;
    LivroCRUD::cadastrar($Livro, $Connect);

    if (isset($Livro->id)) {
        print "Pronto! Tudo feito por aqui...";
    } else {
        $Connect->rollBack();
    }
} else {
    $Connect->rollBack();
    $Connect = NULL;
    print "Algo deu errado...";
}
?>
```